# Is it necessary to convert categorical attributes to numerical attributes to use LabeledPoint function in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, categorical-data

I am new to Pyspark. I have a dataset that contains categorical features and I want to use regression models from pyspark to predict continuous values. I am stuck in pre-processing of data that is required for using MLlib models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary. You have to not only convert to numerical but also encode to make them useful for linear models. Both steps are implemented in `pyspark.ml` (not `mllib`) with:

- `pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexer` - indexing.
- `pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder` - encoding.